# Unconsistent entity object collection state

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, transactions

I am having inconsistent object state when using Hibernate

I have class School that have a collection of student

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "LINK_SCH_STUDENT", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "SCHOOL_ID"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID"))
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
private List<Students> associatedStudents;
```

I have a transactional method that links a student to a school:

```
@Transactional
LinkStudentToSchool (schoolId, StudendID){
flush();
int result = getSession().createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO " + getSchemaName()
+ ".LINK_SCH_STUDENT(SCHOOL_ID, STUDENT_ID) " +
"Values (:recipient_group_id, :contentId)")
}
```

I am writing integration test for this method.

```
@Transactional
TestLinkStudentToSchool {
school =new School ("GeorgiaTech", ....)
schoolId = saveOrUpdate (school)
studentID = saveOrUpdate (new Student ("LazyStudent", ....))

LinkStudentToSchool (schoolId, studentID)

Hibernate.initialize (school.getAssociatedStudent);
school.getAssociatedStudent // RETURN NULL !!!
}
```

Why is this happening, I already called a transactional method to add a student a school (update the link table), but the state of the collection of students
in the school did not get updated !!

Is this a caching issue ? is it because I have nested @transactional?
I will really appreciate any feedback

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start by creating a Scool instance and saving it. It becomes associated to the Hibernate session. At this time, the list of students is null, because you neglected to initialize the list to an empty list (this should be the default state of a new school).

Then you execute a SQL query, like if Hibernate didn't exist and you were using JDBC. Hibernate doesn't know what this query does. It doesn't know that the query inserts a row to the join table. And it can't magically know that this corresponds to a new association between the student and the school. It can't magically initialize the field of your school in memory and replace it with a list containing the student. Don't bypass Hibernate by using SQL queries. Use the entities:

```
// correct default state of a school:
private List<Students> associatedStudents = new ArrayList<>();

...

School school = new School("GeorgiaTech", ....);
session.save(school);
Student student = new Student("LazyStudent", ....);
session.save(student);
// now associate the student with the school:
school.getAssociatedStudents().add(student);

// done. Hibernate will insert the row in the association table for you.
```

Comment: Thank for your reply JB. the only reason I was not using Hibernate for the Link table is that it has a 'deleted' field for soft deleting the association. Using SQL query made easier to set the filed directly. I so know if I should change the design at this point.

Comment: Hibernate won't care at all about this additional column. If you want it to care about it, then the join table must be mapped as an entity, and the column should be mapped as a field of this entity.

Comment: Make sens, merci bien Jean-Baptiste.